# Get css property from class(dynamic) and add it to another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get a css property from a `div` if it's using the `:nth-child` selector to add different colors, and after that add it to a class?I will provide an example

HTML:

```
<div class="blog-post"></div>
<div class="blog-post"></div>
<div class="blog-post"></div>
<div class="blog-post"></div>
etc
```

CSS:

```
.blog-post{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #639b16;
}

.blog-post:nth-child(2n+2){
    border-bottom-color: #64169b;
}

.blog-post:nth-child(3n+3){
    border-bottom-color: #9b5816;
}
.blog-post:nth-child(5n+5){
border-bottom-color: #639b16;
}
```

So far if it looks like the color won't apply,but it is.It's not exactly how my code is, it's a simplified version(don't want to make huge lines of code here).

I'm also looping through all of the `blog-post` and add a class `bla` if some conditions are met

My question is how can I get the `border-bottom-color` of the current `blog-post` and apply it to class `bla` without making a huge script?

Thanks!

Comment: the css is working - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v0x2dytr/1/

Comment: Use `getComputedStyle` to get the style of an element that comes from CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add a css rule is not a good solution. In fact **the best way is to add css class, not css rule**. Also, If this is possible to add a rule to a css class(I believe this is impossible), you want to add `border-bottom-color` rule to `bla` class in the loop and for each `blog-post` class. In this way, the value of `border-bottom-color` rule in `bla` class will be changed each time! I think your approach to problem is not correct.